# How do I UNLOCK my account?

Tags: users, admin, tags, password

My account is locked and I cant figure out how to unlock it. I tried resetting the password, but have yet to receive an email with a new one. Is there an alternative way to logging back on? I recently changed the password and because it is a shared dashboard, I think someone (who was unaware of the pw change) may have tried logging in too many times which is how the account locked.

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t have access to another admin account, you could unlock the account directly in the database.

Change the `lock` value to 0 for the account in the `craft_users` table.